# How is the view getting re-populated when the form validation fails?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following code.  Where its a simple form.  If the validation fails, what the user entered is still showing in the form.  How is that doing that? as in the controller all I do is return a View(), I don't pass the model to it.  It works fine, but I need clarification on why it works

Here is the Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult RsvpForm()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        return View("Thanks", guestResponse); 
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

The View is RsvpForm

```
@model PartyInvites.Models.GuestResponse

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>RsvpForm</title>
</head>
<body>
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.ValidationSummary()
       <p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Name)</p>
       <p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Email)</p>
       <p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Phone)</p>
       <p>
           Will you attend?
           @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend,new[] { 
          new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString},
          new SelectListItem() { Text = "No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString}}, "Choose an option")

       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit RSVP" />



   }
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to an
>   HTTP POST, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely
>   to be redisplaying a form that has failed validation.

You can read about it in more detail here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx